# "Proportional" media queries using viewport-units

Tags: css, media-queries, mobile-safari, viewport-units

**Problem:**

iOS8/Safari doesn't seem to understand / support media queries containing viewport units like: `(max-height: 175vw)`. It works just fine on iOS9 devices though. I tried using `max-aspect-ratio` and `max-device-aspect-ratio` but they're also being ignored.

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working or know of any other way of creating media queries that are not tied to proportions/aspect ratios instead of specific screen sizes?

**Explanation (or, why do I even need this?)**

We're working on an ios/android app using Cordova and instead of having to worry about breakpoints and all different screen sizes, we decided to use viewport units quite extensively and only worry about a few aspect ratio / screen size proportions.

So, right now, the styles we have work fine on devices like iPhone 5, 6, 6+, most Android devices (and any other device that share these proportions or anything in between).

Now, devices like iPhone4 and iPads have considerably different proportions; they're more 'square' per say. To account for that, we just need a media query for 7/4 and below proportions and `(max-height: 175vw)` works just fine on iOS9 and Android devices (we're using Crosswalk for Android, so consider Chrome too), but doesn't seem to work on iOS8/Safari.

**Update:**

Just had an idea. For now I'll use `(max-height: 175vw)` and that should fix all Android devices (at least 4.4 that we're supporting) and iOS9 devices. After that, I may just need an extra media query for iPhone4 and/or iPad.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like **aspect-ratio is supported for media queries** by now, as I have just tested in the current versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari (see [demo](http://codepen.io/avantlalettre/pen/zBVYqm)).

```
 @media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
     .landscape { display: none; }
 }
```

Please take note that you have to [**specify the ratio in form of a division**](https://vasilis.nl/nerd/min-aspect-ratio-mean-look-like/) (e.g. 16/9). Floating point values (e.g. 1.7777) will not supported.

Of course, in a media query, `min-aspect-ratio` is functionally aequivalent to `max-width` with the corresponding value in viewport units (`vh`) – but better supported by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Until viewport units are really supported, you can use `cordova-anyscreen` to accomplish what you want. https://github.com/biodiv/cordova-anyscreen .

You will also be able to support Android down to 4.0, maybe even 2.3 (which might not be important) and iOS 6+.

Proportional Layout is done in reference to a screen with the dimensions 1080*1920. So if you want 50% width you would use 540px. The display is measured by the script and it recalculates the 540px matching the screen.